# Embed images in a mail on laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to display some images in my mail on Laravel 5.3
I'm using `$message->embed($path)` and it works. But for some reasons, the images appear at the end of the mail (on Mac OS Mail and Gmail).

How can I prevent this ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may try the asset function in Laravel

Asset function reference: [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset)